# how to fix scipy.signal.wiener crashes duo to image dimension error?

Tags: python, image-processing, filter, scipy

***hi greetings everybody***

I want to use scipy.signal.wiener function for noise reduction, I found it on scipy [website][1] where they demonstrate it on a randomly generated image rng.random((40, 40)).

```
import cv2 
from scipy.misc import face
from scipy.signal import wiener
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('/content/Hand.jpeg')
filtered_img = wiener(img, (5, 5))  #Filter the image
f, (plot1, plot2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
plot1.imshow(img)
plot2.imshow(filtered_img)
plt.show()
```

when I  run the code like am showing up here, it crashes with a message :

```
----> 8 filtered_img = wiener(img, (5, 5))  #Filter the image
      9 f, (plot1, plot2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
     10 plot1.imshow(img)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py in correlate(in1, in2, mode, method)
    201         return in1 * in2.conj()
    202     elif in1.ndim != in2.ndim:
--> 203         raise ValueError("in1 and in2 should have the same dimensionality")
    204 
    205     # Don't use _valfrommode, since correlate should not accept numeric modes

ValueError: in1 and in2 should have the same dimensionality
```

***it only works if I set mysize = 1.0 or any integer and it gets me a bad and corrupted image, while when the filter had been applied on the random image sample on scipy in the link with mysize = (5,5), it had resulted in a good image**

**how can I apply the filter on my image with mysize = (5,5) without crashing ???**
[1]: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.wiener.html

Comment: Tell us about `img`

Comment: @hpaulj
ok, it's a gray image of a hand, with a size of 22 kilobits and size of (601, 500, 3)
and resolution of 500 * 601

Comment: that's 3d - what does `weiner` expect?

Comment: @hpaulj
you mean it should be 2d image

Comment: @hpaulj do you mean that the image has a zero number of channels

Comment: I want you to study the `weiner` docs, and figure what it requires. I haven't used it myself, and have only glanced at the docs.